# Timber.io + Django + Heroku | How to only display application logs

Tags: django, heroku, logging

I have a Django application running on Heroku with a drain sending logs to my Timber.io source.

Currently, my Timber.io logs display:

- The logs that I wrote in my app to display (All I want)
- `app` logs
- `heroku` logs

[Here is a link to what a section of my Timber.io logs look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoYZa.png) Notice how there are `app web.1` and `heroku router` logs.

I don't want any other logs other than the ones I write in my Django application.

Django code:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
timber_handler = timber.TimberHandler(
    source_id=config('TIMBER_SOURCE_ID'),
    api_key=config('TIMBER_API_KEY'),
    level=logging.DEBUG
)
logger.addHandler(timber_handler)

...

logger.warning('A user has navigated to the homepage') # To reiterate, logs like this are all I want to display in my Timber.io logs.
```

I have sent a few emails posing this question to Timber.io's support email. But, after a week, I haven't received a response.

This is my first question so I apologize if I did something incorrectly. Thanks in advance for responses.

Answer (score 0):

What about defining a custom debug logger

my_logger.py

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
timber_handler = timber.TimberHandler(
    source_id=config('TIMBER_SOURCE_ID'),
    api_key=config('TIMBER_API_KEY'),
    level=logging.DEBUG
)
logger.addHandler(timber_handler)
```

Views.py:

```
from my_logger import logger as debug_logger

debug_logger.warning('A user has navigated to the homepage')
```

Edit:

Looking at their [documentation](https://docs.timber.io/usage/filtering-logs), you can filter on the Timber Side as well.

> In your shell issue the following curl command:
>
> - Replace YOUR_API_KEY with your actual API key.
> - Replace YOUR_ORGANIZATION_ID with your Timber organization ID.
> - Replace FILTER_NAME with the name of your filter (ex: "Drop health check    logs")
> - Replace MATCH with the sub-string that your logs must contain    to qualify dropping.
> - Replace SOURCE_ID with the ID of the relevant source. Add as many as you like.
>
>   ```
>     curl https://api.timber.io/log_filters \
>     -s \
>     -X POST \
>     -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY" \
>     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>     -d '
>       {
>         "organization_id": "YOUR_ORGANIZATION_ID",
>         "name":"FILTER_NAME",
>         "match":"MATCH",
>         "source_ids": ["SOURCE_ID"]
>       }
>     ' \
>     | jq
>   ```

Comment: Using an alias for the logger doesn't appear to be a fix. Also, regarding their filter/drop feature, I'd have to add a protocol for each message Heroku could possibly send. If they had functionality to drop all messages from specific sources like `app` and `heroku` sources, that would be more useful for me.